# How to run agi-script from java

Tags: java, web-services, asterisk, agi

Am trying to develop a project with Asterisk server. I am facing a issue with calling the agi-script from my java web application. I tried many links but still can not able to resolve that. Where am I going wrong on this?and is it possible to call agi-script from web service ?

Answer (score 0):

Agi script should be triggered by Asterisk, but not by 3rd party App. If you need to control Asterisk from 3rd party application, then you should use AMI. You can take a look on call files too, but it has quite limited functionality.

Comment: Yes,i used that AMI for apply config and etc,here my question is Before the call reaches to the asterisk server,is it possible to run the agi-script from web service,if so how to do that kindly help me

Comment: AGI script is not possible to run by 3rd party App(technically you can run it but it will not work with Asterisk properly). What exactly you are trying to do with your code? Maybe you can provide more info and I will recommend you best way how to achieve it?

Comment: Actually am trying run the agi-script from java application and store some fields in db, here i have attached the source code [link](https://github.com/GRajaMca/How-to-run-agi-script-from-java)  ,which i used for reload the dial plan, it's working fine,i know this script are running on CLI and agi-script has to run on agi-bin,but i don't know how to do that

Comment: Cold you please show me what is inside /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/survey1.php?

Comment: This is that code      #!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
include("phpagi.php");
$agi = new AGI();
$agi->answer();

while ( !feof($stdin) )
{
$temp = fgets( $stdin );

$temp = str_replace( "\n", "", $temp );

/*$s = explode( ":", $temp );
$agivar[$s[0]] = trim( $s[1] );*/
if ( ( $temp == "") || ($temp == "\n") )
{
break;
}
}



$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","mynewpassword");
$db = mysql_select_db("asterisk", $con);
$query = "INSERT INTO client_channel (`name`) VALUES ('Jack')";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close($con); 




$agi->hangup();

fclose ($stdin);

?>

Comment: You can't run AGI script from 3rd party App. AGI script should be run by Asterisk.

Check AMI:
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/AMI+Examples

You should use AMI in your case

Comment: am very new to this can i get some suggestion or sample to use that AMI and thanks for your valuable suggestion